# How to determine the size of collection, given the size of a selection and the number of ways to select?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

**Problem**

A gym coach must select $11$ seniors to play on a football team. If they can make their selection in $12,376$ ways, how many seniors are eligible to play?

The answer is $17$, but how do I get there?

**What I’ve tried**

Below are my attempts to solve the equation $$\dbinom n {11} = 12,376$$ and its equivalent $$\dfrac {n!}{11!(n-11)!}=12,376$$

**First**

Simplifying factorials in the last equation I get $$\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\cdots(n-10)}{11!} = 12,376$$

I’ve found out that the numerator in the left part of the equation matches the definition of [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials), but I don’t fully understand this concept. Besides, I’m sure there should be a simple solution that does not involve anything advanced because the problem comes from the first chapter of the book on discrete and combinatorial mathematics intended for beginners.

I’ve tried to simplify the numerator of the left part of the equation as follows:

$(n-1)(n-10) = n^2 -11n + 10$

$(n-2)(n-9) = n^2 -11n + 18$

$(n-3)(n-8) = n^2 -11n + 24$

$(n-4)(n-7) = n^2 -11n + 28$

$(n-5)(n-6) = n^2 -11n + 30$

Let $a = n^2 -11n$, then

$$\dfrac {n(a+10)(a+18)(a+24)(a+28)(a+30)} {11!} = 12,376$$

However, I was unable to simplify it further. Do I miss something from elementary algebra here?

**Second**

Also, I’ve tried to use Pascal’s identity to represent $\dbinom n {11}$ as a sum of binomial coefficients:

$$\large \displaystyle
\begin{align*}
\dbinom n {11} &=
\dbinom {n-1} {11} +
\dbinom {n-1} {10} \\
&=
\bigg[\dbinom {n-2} {11} +
\dbinom {n-2} {10} \bigg] +
\bigg[\dbinom {n-2} {10} +
\dbinom {n-2} {9} \bigg] \\
&=
\dbinom {n-2} {11} +
2 \dbinom {n-2} {10} +
\dbinom {n-2} {9} \\
&=
\dbinom {n-3} {11} +
3 \dbinom {n-3} {10} +
3 \dbinom {n-3} {9} +
\dbinom {n-3} {8} \\
&=
\dbinom {n-4} {11} +
4 \dbinom {n-4} {10} +
6 \dbinom {n-4} {9} +
4 \dbinom {n-4} {8} +
\dbinom {n-4} {7} \\
& 
\vdots \\
&=
\dbinom {11} 0 \dbinom {n-11} {11} +
\dbinom {11} 1 \dbinom {n-11} {10} +
\dbinom {11} 2 \dbinom {n-11} {9} + \cdots +
\dbinom {11} {11}  \dbinom {n-11} {0} \\
&=
\sum_{k=0}^{11} \dbinom {11} k \dbinom {n-11} {11-k} 
\end{align*}$$

Then $$\displaystyle
\sum_{k=0}^{11} \dbinom {11} k \dbinom {n-11} {11-k} =12,376$$.

I tried to apply Vandermonde’s identity here, but actually, I could only prove that the equation above is the same equation I'd started from.

$\displaystyle
\sum_{k=0}^{11} \dbinom {11} k \dbinom {n-11} {11-k} = \dbinom {n-11+11} {11} = \dbinom n {11}$.

Also, I was thinking about using the binomial theorem here. May I rewrite the equation above as $\displaystyle
\sum_{k=0}^{11} \dbinom {11} k x^k y^{11-k}= 12,376$, where $x,y \in R$? If so, then $(x+y)^{11}=12,376$, but what should I do with it?

**Third (continuation of the second)**

Since

$\displaystyle
\sum_{k=0}^{11} \dbinom {11} k \dbinom {n-11} {11-k} = 
\sum_{k=0}^{11} \dbinom {11} k \dbinom {n-11} {k} = 1 + 
\sum_{k=1}^{11} \dbinom {11} k \dbinom {n-11} {k}$,

I can rewrite
$\dbinom n {11} = 12,376$
as
$$\displaystyle 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{11} \dbinom {11} k \dbinom {n-11} {k} = 12,376$$
Then

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{10} \dbinom {11} k \dbinom {n-11} {k} = 12,375
$$

Then I thought about the representation of each term in $\displaystyle
\sum_{k=1}^{11} \dbinom {11} k \dbinom {n-11} {k}$ using Pascal’s identity recursively, as I did previously with $\dbinom n {11}$.

$$
\large
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle &
\sum_{k=1}^{11} \dbinom {11} k \dbinom {n-11} {k} &\\
&=
\dbinom {11} 1 \sum_{k_1=0}^1 \dbinom 1 {k_1} \dbinom {n-12} {k_1} +
\dbinom 2 {k_2} \dbinom {11} 2 \sum_{k_2=0}^2 \dbinom {n-13} {k_2} + \cdots \\
&\qquad+
\dbinom {11} {11} \sum_{k_{11}=0}^{11} \dbinom {11} {k_{11}} \dbinom {n-21} {k_{11}} \\
&=
11 + \dbinom {11} 1 \dbinom {n-12} 1 + 55 + \dbinom {11} 2 \sum_{k_2=1}^2 \dbinom 2 {k_2}\dbinom {n-13} {k_2} + \cdots \\
&\qquad + 1 + \dbinom {11} {11} \sum_{k_{11}=1}^{11} \dbinom {11} {k_{11}} \dbinom {n-21} {k_{11}} \\
& =
11^2-1 + \sum_{k=1}^{11}\dbinom {11} k \sum_{i=1}^{k} \dbinom k i \dbinom {n-(11+k)} i
\end{align*}
$$

Assuming the expression above is correct (which I really doubt),

$11^2-1 + \sum_{k=1}^{11}\dbinom {11} k \sum_{i=1}^{k} \dbinom k i \dbinom {n-(11+k)} i = 12,375$

$\sum_{k=1}^{11}\dbinom {11} k \sum_{i=1}^{k} \dbinom k i \dbinom {n-(11+k)} i = 12,255$

However, it looks like this approach leads to an infinite process since the number of terms on the left side of the equation does not decrease.

Sorry, for such a long post. I was putting as much effort as I could to solve this problem, but I really need some help.

Comment: Have you tried factoring 12376?  On the LHS of your first attempt you have something that is written as a product of many terms; what about on the RHS?

Comment: Another thing you could do is to think about magnitudes.  For example, it's easy to see $n > 15$, since $\binom{15}{11} = \binom{15}{4} < 15^4/4! \approx 2000$ or what-have-you.  But in any case I think your main strategic mistake is to try to manipulate the LHS only without thinking about the RHS.

Comment: Also this is just a curiosity not really related to your question, but: if you were told only that there are $n$ seniors and that the number of ways to choose $k$ of them is 12376, that information narrows it down to choosing 11 (or 6) of 17, or choosing 1 (or all but 1) of 12376, since 12376 is not in this sequence: https://oeis.org/A003015 .  (It is much harder to come up with a good explanation for this!)

Comment: @JBL I've tried to represent RHS as follows: $12,376 = 8192 + 4096 + 64 +16 + 8 = 2^{13} + 2^{12} + 2^{6} + 2^4 + 2^3$, but I cannot see what it gives...

Comment: Well since that's not a factorization I'm not terribly surprised it doesn't help.  Have you tried factoring it?

Comment: Probably, I haven't emphasized it enough in my post, but the problem is from a book for beginners and I am a beginner. So, I hope, the solution is supposed to be something simple and obvious.

Comment: I think the only simple and obvious solution will be to calculate ${{n}\choose{11}}$ for increasingly large values of $n$ unless you reach the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

One way to sort of brute force it is to use the Hockey-Stick identity.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity

If we want to look for $\displaystyle \binom{n}{11} = 12376$ we can rephrase this as

$\displaystyle \sum_{i = 10}^{n-1} \binom{i}{10} = 12376$

If you pull out the first obvious terms you can simplify a bit to

$\displaystyle \sum_{i = 12}^{n-1} \binom{i}{10} = 12364$

At this point you could just try $n$ greater than $12$ up to $17$ since $\displaystyle \binom{17}{10}$ is greater than $12364$.

Its definitely not the fastest way, but worst case you are checking six values.

Addendum:

Another fact you can use is that the prime factorization of $12376$ is $2^3 \cdot 7 \cdot 13 \cdot 17$. A nice fact about the Arithmetic Triangle is that if $n$ is prime, then $n$ divides each binomial coefficient $\displaystyle \binom{n}{r}$ for $1 \leq r \leq n-1$.

So, you could look at the 'prime' rows that show up in the factorization. I'm not sure this always works, but it does in this case. Narrowing it down further, since your $r = 11$, you need only check $n = 13$ and $n = 17$.

Answer (score 3):

If the binomial coefficient $\tbinom{n}{m}$ is divisible by a prime number $p$ then $p\leq n$. It is not hard to factor $12376$:
$$12376=2\times6188=2^2\times3094=2^3\times1547=2^3\times7\times221=2^3\times7\times13\times17.$$
And so this tells you that $n\geq17$. Then it remains to verify that $n=17$ indeed works.